# How to get the proportion of values in a row in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, sum, row, average

Let's say I have the following df:

```
col1|col2|col3
  1 |  3 |  1
  2 |  2 |  1
```

and I would like to have the proportion of values for rows, so stg like this:

```
col1|col2|col3
 0.2| 0.6| 0.2
 0.4| 0.4| 0.4
```

so far, my main problem is how to grab the sum of the rows:

```
mydf["col1_proportion"] = mydf["col1"].apply(lambda x: x / (XXX)  )
```

where (XXX) should be the sum for the given row

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `div` with `sum`

```
out = df.div(df.sum(1),axis=0)
Out[36]: 
   col1  col2  col3
0   0.2   0.6   0.2
1   0.4   0.4   0.2
```

Comment: this works, great!
what does the 1 means in sum(1)? If i delete it, and leave it empty, I get NaN values.

Comment: @biohazard90 yw~ happy coding